# What are the default configurations of Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have two questions regarding `hyperledger playground`:

1. What are the default configurations of `hyperledger fabric` on `hyperledger playground` ?
2. How can I create multiple nodes on `hyperledger playground` ?

Comment: If you have two distinct questions, the best way is to post them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to Hyperledger Composer Playground then there are no default configurations. It can be used to get started with developing business networks and provides a Web Browser mode (which is executes the composer runtime inside the browser and simulates some aspects of a fabric network) to provide a quick way to test those business networks. If you install it locally then it is also capable of connecting to a real hyperledger fabric network where you can deploy your business networks to test inside a real fabric network. 
Hyperledger composer does not provide a Hyperledger fabric network, it works with existing fabric networks and sample fabric networks can be downloaded as described in the composer tutorials
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials

Operational management of a fabric network (such as adding new peers, organisations, channels) is not the purpose of hyperledger composer, you should refer to hyperledger fabric documentation here 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/